# Delete and EDIT API's using expressJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I created DELETE API and in the callback function I have written .remove function to delete a product if the id I have given is present. But when I am giving incorrect input, the result is receiving some object which shouldn't be the case. As there is no data with the Id i have given it should be null or undefined.
Can someone help on this?
Route URL- 
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/products/:productId/delete

Code -

```
let deleteProduct = (req, res) => {
    if (check.isEmpty(req.params.productId)) {
        console.log('productId should be passed')
        let apiResponse = response.generate(true, 'productId is missing', 403, null)
        res.send(apiResponse)
    } else {
        productModel.remove({ 'productId': req.params.productId }, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error Occured.')
                logger.error(`Error Occured : ${err}`, 'Database', 10)
                let apiResponse = response.generate(true, 'Error Occured.', 500, null)
                res.send(apiResponse)
            } else if (check.isEmpty(result)) {
                console.log('Product Not Found.')
                let apiResponse = response.generate(true, 'Product Not Found.', 404, null)
                res.send(apiResponse)
            } else {
                console.log('Product Deletion Success')
                let apiResponse = response.generate(false, 'Product Deleted Successfully', 200, result)
                res.send(apiResponse)
            }
        })
    }
}


let isEmpty = (value) => {
    if (value === null || value === undefined || trim(value) === '' || value.length === 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I give incorrect productId, Ideally it should give 'Product Not found' but the output is coming as Product Deleted Successfully.

Comment: What does `check.isEmpty()` do? Can you please share the code for it? Also, can you please tell what database you are using from where you are removing the product?

Comment: let isEmpty = (value) => {
    if (value === null || value === undefined || trim(value) === '' || value.length === 0) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }

Comment: This check is the library i am using. And Mongo is the database i am using. I am testing my API's using Postman

Comment: In  routes js file, app.post(baseUrl+'/:productId/delete',ecartcontroller.deleteProduct);

Answer (score 0):

The `result` will contain an object no matter if it was successful or not, it will never be empty in this case. Please read the documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/#writeresult).

`check.isEmpty(result)` will always be false.

Comment: Hi Sookie, Can you tell me how to handle the case when we pass incorrect productId as parameter?

Comment: If you pass incorrect productId then number of documents removed will be equal to 0 and then you can use `if (result.nRemoved == 0)`